# rich:calendar and default time

Tags: jsf, calendar, richfaces

I am using two `<rich:calendar>`s to allow the user to enter a date range (from, to) using full days only:

```
<rich:calendar
    id                  = "timeTo"
    value               = "#{listModel.rangeStopErrorTime}"
    datePattern         = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    valueChangeListener = "#{listController.filterFieldChanged}"
    enableManualInput   = "true"
/>
```

If the user wants to specify a single day, both my from and to date will be the same (`e.g., 2013-01-22T00:00:00`). I would like to set the default time of the `to` field to the end of the day (e.g., `2013-01-22T23:59:59`). I tried with the `defaultTime` attribute

```
<rich:calendar
    id                  = "timeTo"
    value               = "#{listModel.rangeStopErrorTime}"
    datePattern         = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    defaultTime         = "23:59:59"
    resetTimeOnDateSelect = "true"
    valueChangeListener = "#{listController.filterFieldChanged}"
    enableManualInput   = "true"
/>
```

but it works only if I change the `datePattern` to include the time (`datePattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"`) and the time will be shown in the input field.

Is there a way to specify a default time without showing it to user?

**Update**:

- `rangeStopErrorTime` is a simple `java.util.Date` attribute with a standard getter and setter:

  ```
  private Date rangeStopErrorTime;

  public Date getRangeStopErrorTime()
  {
      return rangeStopErrorTime;
  }

  public void setRangeStopErrorTime( Date rangeStopErrorTime )
  {
      this.rangeStopErrorTime = rangeStopErrorTime;
  }
  ```

Comment: What type is listModel.rangeStopErrorTime. Maybe post some of the bean class code.

Comment: @roel It's a simple `Date` (see my update)

Comment: You could transform/modify the date on the form submission. Otherwise, there's no default way to handle what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Luiggi Mendoza says, you should do it in the bean. On submit set the time.